# Insufficient privileges to access a table

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

There is a table which when I use to execute a query it gets normally executed but when I compile it in a package it is giving an error for that table saying

> insufficient privileges

Any idea what I can do about it ?

Comment: ask your DB admin to grant you privileges?

Comment: so how am i being able to use the same table in the worksheet... when i am just executing the query ?

Answer (score 2):

The user you are using got the privilege to access the table through a **role**.

Privileges obtained through roles are not in effect inside a PL/SQL program. You need to grant the select (insert,update,delete) privilege directly to the user in question.